# Swift: Fetch XML and check it's well formed

Tags: swift

I want to download an XML and check to see if it can be parsed at all, no schema validation.
I was thinking to write two free functions, to separate concerns and wrap them in a third, public API:

````swift
enum PlistFirmwareFetcher {
    static let firmwarePlistURL = "https://mesu.apple.com/assets/macos/com_apple_macOSIPSW/com_apple_macOSIPSW.xml"
    static private let mimeType = "application/xml"
    
    enum FirmwareDownloadError: Error {
        case CoulNotDownload
        case WrongMimeType
        case InvalidXML
    }
    
    public static func PlistFirmware() async throws -> XMLDocument? {
        let response = try await downloadPlist()
        return try isPlistOk(response.0, response.1)
    }
    
    
    private static func downloadPlist() async throws -> (Data, URLResponse) {
        let response = try? await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: PlistFirmwareFetcher.firmwarePlistURL)!)
        
        guard let response else {
            throw FirmwareDownloadError.CoulNotDownload
        }
        
        return response
    }
    
    private static func isPlistOk(_ plistBinaryData: Data, _ response: URLResponse ) throws -> XMLDocument {
        
        guard let mimeType = response.mimeType,
              mimeType == PlistFirmwareFetcher.mimeType   else {
            throw FirmwareDownloadError.WrongMimeType
        }
        
        guard let document = try? XMLDocument(data: plistBinaryData) else  {
            throw FirmwareDownloadError.InvalidXML
        }
        
        return document
    }
}
```
````

Comment: This shouldn't be an `enum`, a class or a struct would be preferable. A plist validator shouldn't care where it comes from or take care of network requests, apply the Separation of Concerns principle. Accessibility controls should make your code easily testable. The name `isPlistOk` indicates that it should return a boolean.

Comment: I'd gladly accept the answer, thanks!